# Writing to memory address

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

the following compiles without a hitch :

```
movl %eax, 16
```

and segfaults whatever value 16 is replaced with.

I believe I read that modern systems don't allow processes to write to memory addresses. Do I remember correctly?
If so, why does this syntax still survive in GAS?
If not, where is my error, how can I make this line not segfault?

Thank you!

Edit: in case this was the cause for Kerrek SB's comment, this is GNU assembly (AT&T) syntax.

Comment: Kerrek, your second comment is invaluably useful, my heartfelt thanks to you and your descendents to the twelfth generation. As for your first comment, my university teacher disagrees, but he has been wrong before, and may well be once again, no one is perfect...

Comment: His course, translated from french: "Absolute addressing : movl $123, 456 places the value 123 in the four bytes located at addresses 456 to 459, considered as one four-byte word. It is the equivalent of using a global variable in a C program."

Comment: On which operating system ? And are you sure the segfault is on that instruction (which simply loads the constant 16 in register `%eax`)? I believe it can be, so please edit your question to give more context. And of course modern processes are writing into virtual memory address space! You seems confused!

Comment: The tags are "gcc" and "assembler". I (perhaps naïvely) supposed it was sufficient to indicate this used GAS syntax. I then edited my post to reflect this when Kerrek SB appeared to be confused. This is GAS / AT&T syntax, and this does NOT move 16 in eax, which is done with the syntax movl $16, %eax (note the dollar sign and reversed order of arguments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That instruction "moves" (actually copies) 32 bit (`l` for long) value to memory address 16. On a modern OS, that address is not writable (it probably is readable, you can try), so you get segmentation fault.

To write to memory, you need a writable address, such as address of a variable. You specify this with the variables name (check exact syntax from assembler and compiler docs), not by providing an absolute literal address. It would work with literal address, you just can't easily know what it is, so you can't write it.

So writing to memory can and is done all the time in modern OS, it is what most programs spend most of their actual CPU time doing. You just need an address the process is allowed to write to.

Comment: Any reason why the syntax survives? It is possible in C by use of pointers to write to a memory address (and segfault). In this case the syntax is really simple, it would probably be easy for the assembler to refuse a number as the second argument of movl.

Comment: The syntax survives for completeness and because you might need it. You can assemble any code you want, not just code that will run under your current OS in user mode. The assembler shouldn't care, if the cpu supports it, the tools should too. For example, if you are writing a toy OS, you might want to access the vga text memory at physical address 0xb8000 directly. Neither the C compiler nor the assembler know what addresses are going to be valid at runtime, so they can't filter anything out. Also, most invalid pointers don't come as constants.

Comment: The syntax probably survives for "translational" reasons; i.e., the assembler has to "translate" the label "THIS_VARIABLE_NAME" into 012345678h and then physically assemble that into the hexadecimal soup which will be the actual instruction; all this being my total guess, so I welcome correction from smarter people.

Comment: @pouzzler Compiler might wery well produce machine code which writes to absolute address, even if writing such assembly by hand in user space program is not practical. Also kernel might very well contain the exact instruction from your question, even if it is illegal in user space program. And of course assembly language must have syntax for all (documented) CPU machine code instructions, that (to remove need to write machine code as raw byte values) is the whole purpose of assembly language.